# How does the ssh-keyscan command work with the -t option but for the known_hosts file?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

About the `ssh-keyscan` command, if is executed with the `-t` option, such as:

```
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa 192.168.1.X
```

The expected data is returned, such as:

```
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
192.168.1.X ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 XxXxXxX...XxXxXxX
```

The command shown above was tested with 6 different IPs in the same LAN, all worked fine. Furthermore, same successful results obtained with the `ed25519` and `rsa` key types too, such as:

```
ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 192.168.1.X
ssh-keyscan -t rsa 192.168.1.X
```

Therefore until here the `-t` option - stands for *type* - is doing well its work as a filter.
Until here I have a clear understanding of the `-t` option.

**Note**

Without filter or not indicating the key type - no use of the `-t` option - therefore as:

```
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X
```

The data returned for the specific IP includes the 3 key types together.

---

Now, in some tutorials I read about this `-t` option but now working with the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file

Now, having the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, with entries inserted through the following command:

```
ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.X >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Observe the `-H` option, it for apply hash for the hostnames/ips. The same command was executed 6 times, of course it for the 6 different IPs mentioned of the same LAN.

Executing the following command:

```
ssh-keyscan -t <KEY> -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Where *KEY* can be `rsa` or `ecdsa` or `ed25519`

The output is (N lines about):

```
getaddrinfo |1|XxXxXxX=|XxXxXxX=: Name or service not known
...
getaddrinfo |1|ZzZzZzZ=|ZzZzZzZ=: Name or service not known
```

I think it is expected because the hostnames/ips were hashed. *Please, correct me if I am wrong*

Keeping the current content **and** adding again the same content of these 6 IPs but without hash, therefore with:

```
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Observe there is **no** the `-H` option. Then, if is executed the command:

```
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I can see now the data in two blocks

*One*

```
getaddrinfo |1|XxXxXxX=|XxXxXxX=: Name or service not known
```

Not sure if it is expected - remember the previous content remains in the file. Therefore I am assuming that the content shown above is based on according with the key type requested for filtering. *Again, correct me if I am wrong*

*Two* (The **problem** and reason of this post)

```
For each IP appears all the keys
```

Theoretically I should see only the data based - **filtered** - with the key type defined through the `-t` option.

**Question**

- Block 2 should be filtered, right? What is missing or wrong?

**Note**

The tutorials use the command as:

```
ssh-keyscan -t <KEY> -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts | sort -u ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

But I want understand very well the first part before of the pipe (`|`)